# How can I get all related entities of a node programmatically?

Tags: 7, entities

I am writing some drush scripts and find myself needing to get related entities (nodes) of the current node. However I can only find info for constructing views that do this.

Can anyone tell me is there a programmatic way to pull all entities that relate to the current nid with a filter on the entity type?

Ultimately I need to get a list of node ids that relate to the current node id.

The relationship depend on the [relation](https://www.drupal.org/project/relation) module.

Comment: You should mention how your nodes are related to one another to get the answer you're looking for. For example, are you using the Relation or Entity Reference module?

Comment: @shawn-conn Good point. It's using the Relation module.

Comment: To me it would be a `db_query`  (through a script, module or theme)  including the reference field and the row result would return the `entity_target_id`

Comment: @mchar It is looking that way. I'm writing some not so efficient queries to the field_data_endpoints table that seem to be delivering good results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this, you will get all the referenced items of the node being displayed.

```
  $current_path = explode('/', $_GET['q']);
  if ($current_path[0] == 'node' && is_numeric($nid = $current_path[1])) {
    $field = 'my_field';
    $bundle = 'my_bundle';
    $query = db_query("SELECT {$field}_target_id FROM field_data_{$field} WHERE entity_id = :nid AND bundle = :bundle",
      array(
        ':nid' => $nid,
        ':bundle' => $bundle,
      )
    );
    foreach($query as $row) {
      $target_ids[] = $row->{$field . "_target_id"};
    }
    $nodes = node_load_multiple($target_ids);
  }
```

If you have more entity reference fields, you have to expand the query (with more joins) according to your fields.

Comment: I am writing some drush scripts so I don't have the current path. Also I think to find the related nodes you only really need to query the "field_data_endpoints" table when all your content it related via the relations module.

Comment: The current path can be anything, this is just an example, to your script it could be another query fetching all `nids`. The `node` table isn't needed, yes.